# Symmetry acting on a complex fermion operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hilbert-space, symmetry, fermions

Suppose $S$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry operator, i.e. $S^2=1$, acting on the fermion $c_{n}$ via 
$$S c_{n} S^{-1} = \sum_{m} U_{nm} c_{m}$$
and I am interested in $S$ is both linear or anti linear, i.e,. $S i S^{-1}=\pm i$.

> how do we derive from above the action of $S$ on $c_n^\dagger$? 
>   $$S c_n^\dagger S^{-1}= ?$$
>   Naively, I would take the Hermitian conjugate on both sides, which yields 
>   $$(S^{-1})^\dagger c_n^\dagger S^{\dagger}= \sum_m c^{\dagger}_m (U^\dagger)_{mn}$$ and further use $S^{\dagger}=\pm S^{-1}$, we have 
>   $$S c_n^\dagger S^{-1}=\sum_m c^{\dagger}_m (U^\dagger)_{mn}$$

The only thing I am not sure above is whether $S^{\dagger}=\pm S^{-1}$ holds. Any comments are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a homework question, in which you'll need to demonstrate the progress you've already made and ask us what questions you have when trying to answer these questions.

Comment: @N.Steinle edited.